# Getting news articles in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract stories from nbcnews.com. I currently have the following code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The page that I'm getting stories from
url = 'http://www.nbcnews.com/'

data = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

#This is the tag and class that chrome told me "top stories" are stored in
this = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-9"})

#Get the a tags in the previous tag (this is the part that returns FAR too many links

link = [a for i in this for a in i.find_all('a')]

#Get the titles (This works)
title = [a.get_text() for i in link for a in i.find_all('h3')]

#The below strips all newlines and tabs from the title name
newtitle = []

for i in t:
    s = ' '.join(i.split())
    if s in newtitle:
        pass

    else:
        newtitle.append(s)

print len(link)
print len(title)
```

When I run the script, the "Title" list is (mostly) correct with slight variations on the title names on site (title name isn't a problem if it's close to the same thing)

My problem is that the "link" list seems to contain links from all over? Can someone help me with this?

Or if possible, is there an API available for something similar to this? I'd really rather not reinvent the wheel for getting news articles if I can avoid it.

EDIT: changed a typo in a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the webpage in question, it looks like all the newstories are in `h3` tags with the class `item-heading`. You can use BeautifulSoup to select all the story headers and then use BeautifulSoup's `.parent` method to step upwards in the HTML tree and to access the `a href` that they are contained within:

```
In [54]: [i.parent.attrs["href"] for i in soup.select('a > h3.item-heading')]
Out[55]:
[{'href': '/news/us-news/civil-rights-groups-fight-trump-s-refugee-ban-uncertainty-continues-n713811'},
 {'href': '/news/us-news/protests-erupt-nationwide-second-day-over-trump-s-travel-ban-n713771'},
 {'href': '/politics/politics-news/some-republicans-criticize-trump-s-immigration-order-n713826'},
...  # trimmed for readability
]
```

I've used a list comprehension but you could split out into the composite steps:

```
# select all `h3` tags with the matching class that are contained within an `a` link.
# This excludes any random links elsewhere on the page.
story_headers = soup.select('a > h3.item-heading')

# Iterate through all the matching `h3` items and access their parent `a` tag.
# Then, within the parent you have access to the `href` attribute.
list_of_links = [i.parent.attrs for i in story_headers]

# Finally, extract the links into a tidy list
links = [i["href"] for i in list_of_links]
```

Once you have the list of links, you could iterate through it to check whether the first character is a `/` to match only local links and not external links.

Comment: Thank you sir, I've toyed around with basic webpages with BS4, but after catching up on HTML, I wanted to try to navigate around more complex pages. +1 to you. Thank you for helping me out. This will make a nice addition to my voice assistant. What are news articles good for if you get linked to the wrong one, right? ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer if it's solved your problem, it will award the points to me in return. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment, so I can't test the code. When I get home I will test,  if it works I will accept the answer.

Comment: It took a little editing to the code to be sure that I was only getting the results I wanted, but this did work. Once again, thank you sir.